# Rails-style helper for active_admin pages using namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a rails app using activeadmin, in which I would like to control the whole app using the namespaces configured either in the `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` file or when I register the model in AA. The problem comes when I need to explicitly type in `batch_action_admin_rewards` assuming that the namespace is admin. Now, when I change the namespace to something like `hidden`, I have to manually edit all places where these url helpers were invoked to then change the dynamic method being invoked. Isn't there a helper that can introspect the registered model and build up the url for me automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no helper like this, but you can do the following:

```
url_for(action: "batch_action", controller: "#{ActiveAdmin.config.default_namespace}/rewards")
```